# Drop schemas based on pattern match in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

What is the best way to drop all schemas with a user-specified prefix from a database in Snowflake (ANSI SQL)?

Suppose you have a database called `ANALYTICS` and within that database there are multiple schemas such as: `dev_bob_schema1`, `dev_bob_schema2`, `dev_alice_schema1`.

How can you drop only those schemas which are prepended `dev_bob`?

I've got to the stage where I can list the schemas with:

```
use database "ANALYTICS";
select schema_name
from information_schema.schemata
where schema_name ilike 'dev_bob%'
```

But I can't overcome the final hurdle to loop through the response and execute `drop schema ...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do the following:

1. `USE DATABASE ...`
2. `show schemas like ...`
3. `SELECT 'DROP SCHEMA ' || "name" || ';'
   FROM table(result_scan(last_query_id()));`

Paste the output back into a worksheet and run it.

Comment: Thanks for the proposed workflow. I'm stuck on point 3 with the error:
`SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 7 unexpected '‘D'.`

Comment: You probably need to change the type of quote mark being used: it should be ' rather than ‘

Comment: Yes, that's correct. For Snowflake it should read:
`select 'drop schema '||"name"||';' from table (result_scan(last_query_id()))`

Comment: I submitted a quick edit to fix the formatting to use the correct type of quote.

Answer (score 0):

Using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA` and Snowflake Scripting:

Setup:

```
CREATE DATABASE ANALYTICS;
CREATE SCHEMA dev_bob_schema1;
CREATE SCHEMA dev_bob_schema2;
CREATE SCHEMA dev_bob_schema3;
```

Query:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(CONCAT('DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS ', SCHEMA_NAME, ';', CHAR(10)) , '') AS output
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
WHERE SCHEMA_NAME ILIKE 'DEV_BOB_SCHEMA%';
```

Output:

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS DEV_BOB_SCHEMA1; 
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS DEV_BOB_SCHEMA2; 
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS DEV_BOB_SCHEMA3;
```

---

All-in-one:

```
-- dropping schemas and generating output
DECLARE
   OUTPUT STRING DEFAULT '';
   CUR    CURSOR FOR SELECT CONCAT('DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS ', SCHEMA_NAME) AS query
                     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
                     WHERE SCHEMA_NAME ILIKE 'DEV_BOB_SCHEMA%';
BEGIN

   FOR rec IN CUR DO
       OUTPUT := OUTPUT || rec.query || CHAR(10);
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE rec.query;
   END FOR;
   
   RETURN :OUTPUT;
END;
```

Output(Classic UI):

[image]