# how could I retrieve a list of database names with a cursor?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I know I can retrieve a list of database names with 2 SQL statements like this

```
SHOW DATABASES;
SELECT "name" FROM TABLE(result_scan(-1)) WHERE "name" LIKE 'DEV_%';
```

However, how could I do this using a cursor?

I suppose I can't create a cursor with 2 statements, can I?

PS: The truth is I could build my own loop... but I am curious! :-)

Comment: It seems you try to automate some work on multiple database. 1) Use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DATABASES` 2) Operationalize with SQL block example: [Drop schemas based on pattern match in Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71164147/5070879)

Comment: Silly me... I assumed INFORMATION_SCHEMA was only "within" each database.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cursor could read from [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DATABASES](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/databases) view:

```
DECLARE 
   cur CURSOR FOR SELECT database_name 
                  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DATABASES
                  WHERE database_name ILIKE 'DEV_%';
BEGIN
   -- cursor operations here
   NULL;
END;
```